# Triple Integrals Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume formed by $x^2+y^2=9$, $z=0$, and $y=3z$.

I am having trouble with determining the limits of integration. $x^2+y^2=9$ describes a circle centered at the origin with a radius of $3$. It would also be helpful to know how to change the Cartesian limits to polar limits of integration.

I think that the $z$ value for the limit will be from $0$ to $\frac{y}{3}$
The $y$ limits of integration will be from $0$ to $3$. (since the radius is $3$). 
The $z$ limits of integration will be from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Integration is not the problem. It's just visualizing and labeling the limits of integration. 
Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be $\frac{1}{4}$ of the volume of cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 9$ and $z \in [0, 1]$ (since picture is pretty symmetric). So the answer will be $\frac{9}{4}\pi^2$.

Comment: the problem for me is finding the limits of integration

Comment: Just try to visualize it. Firstly infinite cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 9$ and then plane $y = 3z$. And then intersect them.

Answer (score 1):

Use cylindrical coordinates

$$\begin{align}x &= r\cos \theta \\y&= r\sin \theta\\ z&= z\end{align}$$

Where $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi ,\ 0\leq r\leq 3$ and $0 \leq z \leq \frac{1}{3}r \sin \theta$. Then

$$\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}r \sin \theta}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin \theta, z)\  r\ dz\ d\theta\ dr$$

Comment: Don't forget to accept or support the answers given here. If it was useful or helpful let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There are two finite pieces.  One of them has $y,z>0$, the other has $y,z<0$.  They meet at the line $y=z=0$.
One piece has $0<\theta<\pi$,$0<r<3$ and $0<z<\frac13r\sin\theta$.  Put them together into a cylindrical polar integral to find its volume.  The negative piece will have the same volume.